# en el bucle mi gets_s es saltado en la segunda iteracion

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017

estoy pidiendo la nota y los nombres de  10 alumnos pero cuando entra en ña segunda iteracion del for el gets_s es saltado, no me dejar introducir el nombre del estudiante.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student
{
    char name[50];
    int grade;
};

Student students[10];

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Introduce el nombre del alumno:");
        gets_s(students[i].name, sizeof(students[i].name));

        printf("Introduce la nota del alumno:");
        scanf_s("%d", &students[i].grade);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`scanf_s` **no** elimina el salto de línea, que es lo que lee la segunda iteración de `gets_s`. Basta con eliminar ese salto de línea para que la lectura sea correcta.

Para eliminar ese salto de línea **no** es recomendable usar `fflush`, ya que su uso no está garantizado por el estándar, como así indica la [documentación de la función](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/):

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (**but this is not portable expected behavior**).

Si bien no existe una forma *estándar*  de limpiar el buffer de entrada, la opción más común es usar el siguiente bucle:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Por otro lado, ya que etiquetas la pregunta como C++, lo lógico es que uses funciones propias de C++ en vez de las heredadas de C.

En el caso de usar C++, el *stream* de entrada, `stdin` **sí** que dispone de un método específico para descartar caracteres, la función `ignore()`. Esta función descartará el número de caracteres dado salvo que antes se encuentre con el caracter delimitador pasado como parámetro. Si sucede esto segundo, el delimitador se descartará y se dejarán de descartar caracteres.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    int grade;
};

Student students[10];

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Introduce el nombre del alumno:";
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
        std::getline(std::cin,students[i].name);

        std::cout << "Introduce la nota del alumno:";
        std::cin >> students[i].grade;
    }
}
```

`numeric_limits` es una plantilla que tiene información sobre los tipos básicos del lenguaje. En este caso el método `max()` devuelve el número más grande que puede ser almacenado en una variable de tipo `int`. Usar ese valor nos garantiza que antes, pase lo que pase, nos vamos a encontrar con un salto de línea (que es el caracter que nos interesa eliminar).

Comment: aun no tengo mucho conocimiento de las librerias "iostream" ya que estoy aprendiendo primero algunas cosas de C luego las cosas de "iostream". partiendo de eso , quiero utilizar el bucle que mencionaste arriba pero no entiendo como funciona y no se como implementarlo

Comment: @HumbertoEscorce ¿Qué no entiendes exactamente?

Comment: arriba dijiste:"Si bien no existe una forma estándar de limpiar el buffer de entrada, la opción más común es usar el siguiente bucle:

int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);"  y quisiera saber como implementarlo en mi codigo

Comment: @HumbertoEscorce pon ese código donde necesites limpiar el buffer de entrada y listo. Ese código lee caracter a caracter y los va descartando hasta que se topa con un salto de línea

Comment: Gracias eferion e logrado arreglarlo

Comment: @HumbertoEscorce genial. No olvides marcar la respuesta que mejor te haya ayudado como solución.

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco encontré en la documentación de [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=vs-2017) que se debe utilizar la función *fflush(...)* antes de utilizar la función **gets_s(...)** de la siguiente forma:

```
fflush( stdin );
```

De modo que se limpie el bufer de entrada, checa el link que te dejé, hay un ejemplo que seguro te servirá de ayuda. Saludos.